# Make a C# Windows Store app wait for an unzip to finish

Tags: c#, windows-8, zip, async-await

I'm trying to make an epub parsing app in a Windows Store with C#, and it won't wait for the archive (epubs are actually zip files) to finish extracting before it tries to parse the not-yet-existing table of contents. How do I make my app be a bit more patient?

I've tried making my UnZip() function return a task and having the epub constructor (epub is a class) use UnZip().Wait(), but that just freezes the app. What do I do?

Edit: Here's my relevant code:

```
public class epub
{
    public string filename;
    private StorageFolder unzipFolder;
    private IList<epubChapter> _contents;
    private bool _parsed = false;
    public bool parsed { get { return _parsed; } } //Epub and contents are fully parsed

    public epub(string newFilename)
    {
        _contents = new List<epubChapter>();
        filename = newFilename;
        UnZipFile().Wait();
        getTableOfContents();
    }

    private async Task UnZipFile()
    {
        var sourceFolder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
        StorageFolder localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

        unzipFolder = await localFolder.CreateFolderAsync(filename, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

        using (var zipStream = await sourceFolder.OpenStreamForReadAsync(filename))
        {
            using (MemoryStream zipMemoryStream = new MemoryStream((int)zipStream.Length))
            {
                await zipStream.CopyToAsync(zipMemoryStream);

                using (var archive = new ZipArchive(zipMemoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Read))
                {
                    foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
                    {
                        if (entry.Name != "")
                        {
                            using (Stream fileData = entry.Open())
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    await unzipFolder.GetFileAsync(entry.Name);
                                    Debug.WriteLine("File at {0} already exists", entry.Name);
                                    continue;
                                }
                                catch (FileNotFoundException)
                                {
                                    Debug.WriteLine("Creating file {0}", entry.Name);
                                }

                                StorageFile outputFile = await unzipFolder.CreateFileAsync(entry.Name, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

                                //Debug.WriteLine("Output file created at {0}", outputFile.Path);
                                using (Stream outputFileStream = await outputFile.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
                                {
                                    await fileData.CopyToAsync(outputFileStream);
                                    await outputFileStream.FlushAsync();
                                }
                            }

                            if (entry.Name == "toc.ncx")
                            {
                                Debug.WriteLine("toc.ncx found in epub file; parsing it");
                                getTableOfContents();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void getTableOfContents()
    {
        string contentsPath = unzipFolder.Path + @"\toc.ncx"; //The file is always called this in valid epubs

        try
        {
            XDocument toc = XDocument.Load(contentsPath);
            string nameSpace = getNameSpace(toc);
            XElement navMap = firstElementNamed(toc.Root, "navMap");
            parseNavPoints(navMap, nameSpace, 0);
            _parsed = true;
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("File toc.ncx was not found!");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Show Code, harder to do much without it.

Comment: How about using `await` on the `UnZip` instead of `Wait`?

Comment: @Romoku: I tried using await on the UnZip (and moving the call for the UnZip() into a new function because constructors can't be async), but that didn't help.

Comment: Yeah your class is doing too much. You code is executing async, but it won't execute parallel which is why it is freezing your UI.

Comment: If it's doing too much, what should it not be doing and what should be doing it?

Comment: Just wrapping the UnZip file into a Task should run the operation in Parallel. See https://gist.github.com/Romoku/5758146.

Comment: You should apply the suffix **Async** to all async task returning methods to help users of the API understand how it should be used.
If you look at the framework APIs you're using, you **await** on 'SomethingAsync' but not on your own API.

Comment: Oh yeah, thanks. I'll do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, your question seems to be: How do I call an `async` method from a constructor?

The short answer is that you don't, instead create an `async` factory method for your class.

Longer answer: As you noticed, [if you call `Wait()`, your code will block](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). You can't use `await`, because constructors can't be `async`. And if you don't do anything, the constructor is going to return too early.

The solution here is to use an `async` factory method instead of a constructor. Something like:

```
private epub(string newFilename)
{
    _contents = new List<epubChapter>();
    filename = newFilename;
}

public static async Task<epub> CreateAsync(string newFilename)
{
    var result = new epub(newFilename);
    await result.UnZipFile();
    result.getTableOfContents();
    return result;
}
```

For some more information and alternative solutions, see [Stephen Cleary's article about `async` and contructors](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html).